# If $\sum a_nb_n$ converges so does $\sum a_{\sigma n}b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\{a_n\},\{b_m\}\in\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ such that $\sum_{(n,m)\in\mathbb{Z}^4}a_nb_m<\infty$. Does it mean that for every permutation $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, $\sum a_{\sigma(n)}b_m<\infty$?

I thought maybe using the convolution theorem with Poisson summation formula but I can't see how summation on functions evaluated on a lattice can be useful here.

**EDIT/Motivation:** I had a function $f,g_n\in L^2(\mathbb T^2)$ with $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}\hat f(n)g_n(x)=0$ and then I wanted to show that $\sum \hat f(\sigma(n))g_n(x)=0$ as well by expanding $g_n$ into a Fourier series.

Comment: what is $\ell^2$ ?

Comment: @terrace $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2} |a_n|^2<\infty$.

Comment: $\sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^4} a_nb_n$???? where's the m

Comment: also you should say how you are summing these things over $\mathbb{Z}^4$ or $\mathbb{Z}$, since there is cancellation

Comment: What is actually needed here is the _definition_ of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}c_n$ for not-necessarily-nonnegative $c_n$.

Comment: @metamorphy what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the limit construction assumed. In the one-dimensional case (i.e., with $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}^2$) it is understood. What is _your_ definition of this "two-dimensional" sum (in the absence of absolute convergence, of course)?

Comment: @metamorphy Hölder inequality (involving no cancellations and only absolute values) would means that $a_n,b_n$ are both absolutely convergent.

Comment: (I could easily understand it in the language of nets, when we say $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}c_n$ is the limit of $\sum_{n\in N}c_n$ with finite subsets $N$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ considered to form a directed set under inclusion - but then it is equivalent to absolute convergence...)

Comment: @metamorphy Assuming absolute convergence, can we answer this question?

Comment: Ok. A related question I had in mind: If the first sum is 0, so does the second one?

Comment: Yes, the sums always exist and are equal under these conditions (I mean, with absolute convergence).